# internal_type file_reference in type group in TYPO3 8 LTS

Tags: typo3

I tried the following tca:

```
        'file' => [
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'group',
            'internal_type' => 'file',
            'allowed' => 'gif,jpg',
            'max_size' => 1000,
            'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/pics/',
            'show_thumbs' => 1,
            'size' => 3,
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 200,
            'autoSizeMax' => 10
        ],
    ],
```

which i took from an example in the doumentation. But instead of file i need

```
'internal_type' => 'file_reference',
```

which throws the following error when using the wizard in the backend:

#1288965219: $className must be a non empty string. (More information)
InvalidArgumentException thrown in file
typo3_src-8.7.8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php in line 3874.

Any idea why this does not work? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a bug in typo3 core. In the file

/typo3_src/typo3/sysext/recordlist/ext_tables.php

are three element browsers defined:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ElementBrowsers']['db'] =  \TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\Browser\DatabaseBrowser::class;
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ElementBrowsers']['file'] =  \TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\Browser\FileBrowser::class;
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ElementBrowsers']['folder'] =  \TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\Browser\FolderBrowser::class;
```

an element browser for file_reference is missing. But there is no special browser needed - the only difference between file and file_reference is where the files will be saved, and this is not the task of the element browser. If i add this line:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ElementBrowsers']['file_reference'] =  \TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\Browser\FileBrowser::class;
```

all works as expected.

I posted it on forge:

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82873

---

so it is easy to fix: i added the following lines in my ext_tables.php:

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
   // activating file browser for file_reference: 
   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ElementBrowsers']['file_reference'] =  \TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\Browser\FileBrowser::class;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended to build TCA for FAL relations yourself. You should [use the TYPO3 API](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FileAbstractionLayerReference/UsingFal/Tca/Index.html) for that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is an old extension from TYPO3 4.5 with hundreds of files in it and i have to make it run on TYPO3 8. It is just updating a running tcs configuration from 4.5 to 8.